# If Else on joining tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: **tbl_users, tbl_connection, and tbl_support**. One user can add multiple support requests.

Important Field in the tables:

1. If user has locked his profile  : tbl_users.privacy="locked"
2. Check if two persons are friends: tbl_connection.request_from="1", tbl_connection.request_to="2", tbl_connection.status="a"

On the support's search page if the profile is open, show all the requests from that user but if a user has locked his profile then check whether that user is friends with the logged-in user.

Any suggestion on this query? Tried to write the query but didn't work.

Comment: can you add your query that you have tried

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: using: MySQL and my written query is throwing SQL errors, that's why I haven't included them here. @jarlh

Comment: Provide a sample (online fiddle with some data, or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, up to 10 rows per table) and desired output for sample data and some definite "the logged-in user" identifier (with explanations).